# Run method when viewcontroller is accessed from another vc being dismissed

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, viewdidload

Let's say I have my initial vc called VC1, then I have a second one called VC2. VC1 has a segue to VC2, on VC2 there is a button that will dismiss VC2 and then show VC1. Once VC1 loads I want to run a method but I can't do that in view did load so where can I do it?

[VC1] -> [VC2]

Comment: Use delegate method. If you don't know about it refer this : https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: call that method in viewWillAppear instead of calling in viewDidLoad

Comment: In addition to @chandra1234 you can also use unwindToSegue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a delegate method to achieve this. In the method you call to dismiss VC2 call the delegate. You can implement this delegate in VC1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `Unwind Segue` for dismissing the VC2 and call methods in VC1. It is very easy and requires less coding.

In your VC1 add below method:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
    print("Hello")
}
```

In `storyboard` right click on `Exit icon` of VC1 and and connect a segue to VC2:

[image]

Then in `storyboard` in VC2 select the `unwindSegue` and name it :

[image]

now in the method where you are dismissing the VC2 just add:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "dismissSegue", sender: self)
```

you can also pass data from VC2 to VC1.

Answer (score 0):

In VC1:
Delegate of VC2 and in VC1 Controller in Class or extension

add the delegate method into VC1 that would called after dismiss the VC2

In VC2:
Add the protocol of VC1 and make the object of Protocol delegate then its segue exit it goto VC1 Delegate method.

Example:

**VC1:**

```
extension VC1, myCustomVC2Delegate {
    func didCloseDelegate() {
        // Your function or method Called here
    }
}
```

**VC2:**

```
protocol myCustomVC2Delegate {
    func didCloseDelegate()
}
import UIKit

class VC2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: myCustomVC2Delegate?

    @IBAction func onTapGotoVC1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoVC1", sender: self)
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "gotoVC1" {
           if self.delegate != nil {
            self.delegate?.didCloseDelegate()
        }
     } 
}
```