# how to properly pass data from one viewcontroller's selected cell to previous viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview

suppose I have two viewcontroller called A and B. In my viewcontroller B I have a tableview in it. When I selected a cell in my tableview, I want to pass that information back to A.

I have a dictionary that is of the following:

```
myData = [String: DataModel]
```

where DataModel takes the form of

```
struct DataModel{
    var address = ""
    var name = ""
}
```

I want to send the selected cell's key in B back to A. How should I go about doing that?

thanks for your help

Comment: Use delegate to pass data

Comment: How you are going from A to B ?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277695/run-method-when-viewcontroller-is-accessed-from-another-vc-being-dismissed/51278939#51278939 . Both delegate and unwind segue is answered in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add this before `class BViewController:`

   ```
   protocol ClassBViewControllerDelegate: class {
       func didSelectTableViewCell(onRow row: Int)
   }
   ```
2. Create a delegate property in `BViewController`:

   ```
   weak var delegate: ClassBViewControllerDelegate?
   ```
3. Implement tableView delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
           let row = indexPath.row
           delegate?.didSelectTableViewCell(onRow: row)
   }
   ```
4. Tell `ClassAViewController` that its conforms to `ClassBViewControllerDelegate` as such:

   ```
   class ClassAViewController: UIViewController, ClassBViewControllerDelegate {
   ```
5. Bind `ClassAViewController` and `ClassBViewController` at an appropriate place in `ClassAViewController` such a, for instance, `prepareForSegue:sender:`

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifierXYZ" {
           if let vc = segue.destination as? ClassBViewController {
               vc.delegate = self
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Use delegate method `didSelectTableViewCell(onRow row: Int)` *of delegate contract* `ClassBViewControllerDelegate` in `ClassAViewController`:

   ```
   func didSelectTableViewCell(onRow row: Int) {
       print("Selected table view row is:", row)
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the fast response. When I followed your example it didn't print anything. I suspect it may be something about the segue. Do you mind explaining it more to me?

Comment: nvm got it. I took out the segue.identifier part and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Segue is used when one intends to move to another View Controller, and is using storyboards for views and controllers. In case one is creating ViewController in code, one usually set the delegate property on in it after initializing it, and before presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) or navigationController.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

Using completion block or by using delegates you can achieve this.
Using blocks you can code like this:

In your `B VC` create one property for completion block.

```
var cellSelectionCallBackHandler: ((DataModel, Int) -> Void)?
```

Set the `cellSelectionCallBackHandler` property from `VC A`.

```
VCObjectB.cellSelectionCallBackHandler = { (data, index) in
 // Use your data here
}
```

From `VC B` call the completion handler on selecting cell like this

```
cellSelectionCallBackHandler?(yourData, index)
```

Any doubt plz comment.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate method can be used to achieve it. The place/method where you call to dismiss B call the delegate. You can implement this delegate in A.

You can also have a singleton dataHandler class, where you can set and get required properties and can access it from anywhere within your project.